# Camera for a toddler

Tags: equipment-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good set of features to look for in a camera for kids?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/what-is-a-good-set-of-features-to-look-for-in-a-camera-for-kids)

I'm looking for a digi cam for my almost 3 year old (for her birthday).  The kid's cameras are overpriced and not awesome.  I understand that the basic need is for the camera to stand up to being dropped and such, but I really can't see spending even $30 on a 0.3mp camera (seriously.  0.3mp).  Are there digi cams out there that can stand up to a semi-beating?  She's actually pretty gentle with stuff so it's not going to get thrown or smashed against the wall or anything.  I'm looking for cheap.  Doesn't have to be super excellent specs-wise, just better than 0.3mp.

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/what-is-a-good-set-of-features-to-look-for-in-a-camera-for-kids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We bought a VTech KidiZoom on sale for my daughter's 4 year old birthday.  They market it as 2MP, but only in the fine print do you realize the sensor is 0.7MP and you can upsample.  Still, it produces decent pictures, seems to handle abuse, and shoots video and has some games which it's been a delight to see our daughter discover.

It's been about 6 months and I still recommend it, if you can find it for a price you like.

Comment: +1 - the little lad here at home has one of these as well. It's still alive.

Comment: I should add the surprising use of video for a little kid is not them shooting video, but using it strictly for the audio recording.  My daughter records herself singing songs and talking in funny voices, and this amuses her for long periods of time.