# Which camera is best in the beginning of photography?

Tags: camera-recommendation, photography-basics

I am going to start learning photography, can you please suggest which type of camera or phone camera i should buy on beginning of photography?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good camera for a beginner looking to learn it all from a technical standpoint?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13182/what-is-a-good-camera-for-a-beginner-looking-to-learn-it-all-from-a-technical-st) or [What is the best camera to buy for a child to help them learn about photography?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16755/what-is-the-best-camera-to-buy-for-a-child-to-help-them-learn-about-photography) Please have a look on those answers and see if they can help you find an answer to your question

Comment: @Kapil: Please see the type of questions that are covered and not covered on this site [here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Kapil: In general, your best bet is to get help with a specific problem your are facing and could not solve. If you cannot select such a topic, the best approach is that you take a general photography-related book or site e.g. [Cambridge in Colour](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/), look around, find interesting topics to cover, e.g. portraiture or landscape photography or... whatever, and then ask questions about that. Still, gear-related questions will invite mostly opinion-based answers, and your question probably will get flagged.

Comment: @All: Thanks for giving answer, also i want to say that please update old threads like "DSLR" thread which is mentioned above is almost three year old, in between those three years lots of new cameras launched. Apologize if you don't like. :)

Comment: @Kapil Please read the answers on those posts, some of them don't just suggest a specific camera, but also how to find the camera you should be looking at. What I'm trying to say is that even though the questions are 3 years old, the answers are still valid.

Comment: The fact that there are new cameras all the time is specifically why we don't want a constant stream of "what's the best camera *this* month" questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the assumption that you own any form of digital camera (including in your phone) from the past few years, my answer would be to just use that to begin with. In a while, you'll have a much better idea of what sort of photography you're interested in and can then make a buying decision based on that - otherwise you're at risk of spending money on something you don't want/need/like.

Comment: "The best camera is the one that's with you."  as Chase Jarvis has probably made a few bucks out of saying...  :)