# Is a used point and shoot digital compact a good solution to get a camera for my kid with minimal focus/shutter lag?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, point-and-shoot

I am trying to get a kid interested in photography and am looking for a camera *that has no shutter lag/delay* for a 9-10 year old kid. Probably a used point and shoot to keep the cost low (<$200). But all of my point and shoot cameras, which are well past 10 years old, have a significant focus/shutter lag. This causes them to take blurry pictures as they do not realize the photo has not been taken yet as they move on.

The main thing I am looking for is the ability to quickly focus and take the picture.

I do realize a smart phone could be an option, but I want them to have a real camera and not get distracted by all the other things a smart phone does. I also do not think they are quite yet at the point where a smaller mirrorless would work. I am also interested in a point and shoot as it is small enough for them to carry and will have a zoom built in (verses needing multiple lenses). Am I on the right track or am I looking for a unicorn?

Comment: If you want instant shutter actuation on pressing the shutter button, then you probably need to go back to the fully mechanical days - before plastic cameras and autofocus mechanisms and digital imaging. I'm not sure there really is an "answer" anyone here can give you for this - there isn't any "holy grail" P&S that is the clear best choice. Based on your budget, you will just have to find what you can find. A 9-year-old should be plenty smart/aware/calm/sensible enough to learn good photo-taking technique.

Comment: See also: [What is the best camera to buy for a child to help them learn about photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/16755) | [What non-toy camera would be good for a child?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/5674) | [What is a good set of features to look for in a camera for kids?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2585)

Comment: Perhaps their first lesson should be about timing, not finding a device that will make up for their impatience. How is a fully automatic perfect picture taker going to teach them anything, if it does everything for them? Take them out with one of your old cameras.