# compact camera for my son?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-recommendation, children

The guy is 9 yr old, and appears to enjoy taking photos. I don't think I'll give him access to my camera system and lenses. :) But I'm thinking to find him a neat little compact camera.

Requirements: Cheap. Configurable, within reason - would be nice if he could tweak the ISO, shutter and aperture manually, if he is so inclined. Also, it would help if the camera is not a total piece of junk.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good set of features to look for in a camera for kids?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/what-is-a-good-set-of-features-to-look-for-in-a-camera-for-kids)